# .find() doesn't work as expected on DOMNodeInserted

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dom, datepicker

I have a project which uses the `jquery-ui datepicker`. This date picker uses older icon that i want to change without modifiying the code of the `jquery-ui-{version}.js` in case of future updates.
Also, i can't use another datepicker because there is already a lot of work related to this datepicker and changing all of it would be an absolute waste of time and will possibly break the current application.

Because the datepicker is an element created via javascript, i thought that i could use the event `DOMNodeInserted` to modify the class of the element i want.

The architecture of my datepicker looks like this : 
[image: datepicker-architecture]

and here is the code i wrote :

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted','div.ui-datepicker',function(e){

    var element = e.target;

    var prev = $(element).find('div.ui-datepicker-header').find('a.ui-datepicker-prev').find('span.ui-icon');
    var next = $(element).find('div.ui-datepicker-header').find('a.ui-datepicker-next').find('span.ui-icon');
    //The prev and next elements are not the ones i am looking for

    $(prev).removeClass();
    $(next).removeClass();

    $(prev).empty();
    $(prev).addClass('fas');
    $(prev).addClass('fa-chevron-left');

    $(next).empty();
    $(next).addClass('fas');
    $(next).addClass('fa-chevron-right');

});
```

As i wrote as a comment in the code, the prev and next objects are not right.
Only the first `.find()` worked. When i print the element on the console, it prints the element `div.ui-datepicker-header` as an element for `prev` and `next`. I tried separating the retrieval so to locate where the problem is, but even the `.find('a.ui-datepicker-prev')` doesn't work. There is no error but it still retrieves the parent eventhough i am using it to find its children. I tried using `.children('a.ui-datepicker-prev')` but nothing has changed.

What triggers me is that, if i take the exact same code and put it anywhere but in the `.on('DOMNodeInserted')` event, it works. I am a bit stuck here and i couldn't find somebody with the same problem, if you have, please share.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: `.find('div.ui-datepicker-header')` is unneeded

Comment: @evolutionxbox i tried what you said and you were right, but i can't understand why? It makes sense regarding the architecture of the elements

Comment: It's because `find` _"Get[s] the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element"_

Comment: @evolutionxbox So the fact that it works outside of the .on('DOMNodeInserted') is simply a bug?

Comment: It depends on what order the JS is called. I'm not familiar with `DOMNodeInserted` so I don't know if that's a good event to run code on. Who knows if `.ui-datepicker-header` exists at that point?

Answer (score 0):

```
var prev = $(element).find('div.ui-datepicker-header').find('a.ui-datepicker-prev').find('span.ui-icon');
var next = $(element).find('div.ui-datepicker-header').find('a.ui-datepicker-next').find('span.ui-icon')
```

shoud be

```
var prev = $(element).find('div.ui-datepicker-header a.ui-datepicker-prev span.ui-icon');
var next = $(element).find('div.ui-datepicker-header a.ui-datepicker-next span.ui-icon');
```

Comment: Same problem :/

Comment: can't you just target the element without the find() var prev = $(' #ui-datepicker-div div.ui-datepicker-header a.ui-datepicker-prev span.ui-icon');

Comment: Not a bad idea, but i actually got the solution from a previous comment, the 'div.ui-datepicker-header' is not needed, it works after that